# What are interesting examples of still uncomputed cohomology rings?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, homology-cohomology

It seems, that very many cohomology rings of interesting spaces have been computed. For example the integral cohomology rings of $SO(n)$, $Spin(n)$, $U(n)$, $SU(n)$, $Sp(n)$, the real and complex Grassmannians, the real and complex Stiefel manifolds are known. What are the most important examples of spaces of which the (singular) cohomology (with some coeffitients) is not known?

Comment: Every space that is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex (and this covers lots of spaces, in particular all manifolds) has computable (co)homology as long as you know the CW decomposition. So I think that if such examples exist they are most likely "pathological".

Comment: Yes, but one of the points is, that one does not always know a CW decomposition. Consider for example an Eilenberg-MacLane Space $K(G,n)$ for some group $G$ (it doesn't even have to be very complicated). Then it totally unclear from the definition of $K(G,n)$ what a CW-decomposition could be, as one has to deal with (complicated) homotopy groups. And even if you have got a CW-decomposition you would still have to analyse it. So one could rephrase the questions as: Are there interesing examples, where the CW-structure has not been found, or analysed?

Comment: @freakish That's a bit optimistic. It would be much more complicated to "write down" a CW decomposition (whatever that means) of a random space than it would be to compute its cohomology. For example, I dare you to try and write down a CW decomposition of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ – and yet computing its cohomology is very easy... It's a bit like saying that computing with groups is easy, because every group has a presentation. But then how do you find the presentation, and how do you make actual computations with that presentation that may be horribly unwieldy?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi how do you compute cohomology of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$? This doesn't look trivial to me. Anyway I agree that the CW way is sometimes hard but the question was not about difficulty but examples of spaces for which cohomologies are unknown. My point was that you would probably (with the emphasis on "probably") have to search outside of CW world.

Comment: @freakish Over $\mathbb{Q}$ it's very easy, like all Lie groups. Over $\mathbb{Z}$, it's a bit harder. Anyway, my point is that you **don't** have to search outside the world of CW complexes. Consider configuration spaces for example – computing their cohomology is very hard.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Again, this is not about difficulty, is it? Are there configuration spaces with unknown cohomologies? If there are then I encourage you to post that as an answer. BTW AFAIK not all of them are CW, even when the underlying space is? I have very little knowledge about them.

Comment: @freakish Really, the question is "are there spaces for which the cohomology of configuration spaces is known?" Until recently, to my knowledge, it was not possible to compute the cohomology ring of configuration spaces of manifolds in full generality. Since then there has been some results in my own work (partly j/w Campos, Lambrechts, Willwacher). If you are just interested in Betti numbers then you have this whole stability business (too many people to list in this comment). Recently there was a paper of Petersen to compute Betti numbers of configuration spaces of arbitrary spaces.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi why not post it as an answer?

Comment: So it seems, that configuration spaces are an important class of spaces with unknown cohomology. Could you maybe explain why these (the spaces and their cohomology) are of special interest or importance? I would really appreciate this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

People [know in principle](https://mathoverflow.net/a/180657/2893) how to compute the cohomology groups of the spaces $K(S_n,1)$ — the classifying spaces of the symmetric groups $S_n$, which you can think of as the spaces of $n$-tuples of points in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.   But you'll never see them tabulated anywhere, except for some special cases, because 'in principle' doesn't mean it's easy!  I wish someone would work them out more explicitly.